# GNU `sort` command fails to sort with stable and (general) numeric sorting turned on

Tags: bash, sorting, command-line

I came across a rather strange situation when using GNU `sort` 8.4 and 8.24 with different sorting methods:

Specifying stable and numeric sorting returns the original list:

```
$ printf '"A"\n"C"\n"B"\n' | sort -sn -k1,1
"A"
"C"
"B"
$ printf '"B"\n"A"\n"C"\n' | sort -sn -k1,1
"B"
"A"
"C"
```

...whereas specifying only a single sorting method works fine:

```
$ printf '"B"\n"A"\n"C"\n' | sort -n -k1,1
"A"
"B"
"C"
$ printf '"B"\n"A"\n"C"\n' | sort -g -k1,1
"A"
"B"
"C"
$ printf '"B"\n"A"\n"C"\n' | sort -s -k1,1
"A"
"B"
"C"
```

Question: Is the stable sort truly incompatible with (general) numeric sorting, or am I missing something here?

In that case, I would have expected an error as shown below:

```
$ printf '"B"\n"A"\n"C"\n' | sort -gn -k1,1
sort: options '-gn' are incompatible
```

Thanks in advance, any insight as to why this occurs is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the love of all that is holy: `printf '"A"\n"C"\n"B"\n' | sort -sn -k1,1`!

Comment: A, B, and C are not numerical values. Not sure how `sort -n` handles that. Actually this output makes sense assuming that `sort -n` assigned the same value (likely 0) to all non-numeric inputs, a stable sort would just output the same sequence as it was input.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Edited the example for better clarity, thanks for pointing how convoluted the code was

Comment: @KurtStutsman But `-n` sorts it fine, regardless of whether A, B and C are numerical values.  I was only able to bypass sorting altogether by combining `-s` and `-n` (or `-g`)

Comment: Use The Source, Luke

Comment: Note: sorting numeric values works fine with `-sn`:  `printf '1\n3\n2\n' | sort -sn -k1,1`. Maybe that's worth a coreutils bug report.

Comment: @NicolasDeJay You're using `sort -n` in an undocumented way and concerned about the output you're getting. As far as I can tell sort does not give any documented way of handling non-numeric data when `-n` is used. I was noting that the output with `-sn` is correct assuming it assigns the same value to all non-numerical data. You would have to check the source to see why it does a lexical sort with just `-n` given.

Comment: @KurtStutsman Thanks.  Would you care to write it up as an answer?  I will select it.  For some reason, it did not occur to me that this could simply be undocumented behaviour.

Comment: @t0r0x Thanks.  I will submit a bug report.

Comment: The answer from @rici is better than mine. You should accept that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric sort sorts by the longest numeric prefix of the sort field, ignoring leading whitespace. The numeric prefix is allowed to be empty: "An empty digit string shall be treated as zero".

Stable sort retains the original order for lines whose keys compare equal, so if you stable numeric sort lines not starting with numbers, the output will be identical to the input.

The quote above is from the [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html); the full documentation for gnu sort can be found with `info sort` if documentation is correctly installed on your machine, or via the url at the bottom of the `sort` manpage, from which I extracted [this link to the -n option](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#index-_002d_002dnumeric_002dsort).

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` utility man page does not document the behavior of the `-n` option when used on non-numeric input. Any attempt to explain the behavior would be speculation without checking the source. Even then, the answer may only apply to that particular implementation.